# PHP: Encoding issue when socket_read cyrillic text

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I am using `socket_read` function in PHP to read data transmitted from java app. But when I try to transmit cyrillic text - PHP incorrectly interprets it.

Java side:

```
...
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket connection = socket.accept();
DataOutputStream response = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

String responseStr = "коти"; //cyrillic text
response.writeBytes(responseStr);
response.flush();
response.close();
...
```

PHP side:

```
...
$response = "";
$next = '';
while ($next = socket_read(static::getSocket(), self::READ_PORT)) {
$response .= $next;
}
echo "<br>Response: " . $response . "<br>";
...
```

Output:

```
Response: :>B8
```

Expected output:

```
Response: коти
```

it works fine with Latin letters. Function `mb_convert_encoding` does not help.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is on Java side. There is a problem with using writeBytes to output multibyte string.
[Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeBytes-java.lang.String-) said "Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by discarding its high eight bits.".

You can use writeByte instead of writeBytes.
Convert the String to a byte array and output it using writeByte.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution: as Mary said, there was a problem with using `writeBytes` to output multibyte string. Solution:

```
   ...
    BufferedWriter bufOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));

        bufOut.write(responseStr);
        bufOut.newLine();
        bufOut.flush();
        bufOut.close();
    ...
```